# How many combinations are there in a set in which some of the elements are indistinguishable?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm trying to work out how many unique combinations (not permutations) there are when **some** of the elements in the set are indistinguishable. For context, I'm actually considering unique products of combinations of prime factors of a number, which can of course involve duplicate prime numbers.

For example, the set $\{1,1,2,3\}$. To work out the number of combinations of 2 items from this set of 4, I may compute ${4 \choose 2} = 6$. However, because two of the elements of the set are identical, this leaves me with some duplicates. The 6 combinations would be $\{1,1\}$, $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{2,3\}$. In this simple case, I can see that removing 2 elements will give the correct number of combinations but I'm struggling to see how to generalise this for other more complicated sets with multiple repetitions, and choosing more than 2 elements.

Alternatively, there are 3 unique elements. I could compute ${3 \choose 2} = 3$ and manually add the 1 missing element, $\{1,1\}$. Again, this becomes less trivial when there are many elements and many repetitions and I struggle to see where to start generalising it.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: An approach is to use generating functions.   You represent the two $1$s with $(1+x+x^2)$, the one $2$ with $(1+x)$, the one $3$ also with $(1+x)$ and then expand $(1+x+x^2)(1+x)(1+x)$ $=1+3x+4x^2+3x^3+x^4$.  So the answer to your example for the number of two-element compositions is the coefficient of $x^2$ which is $4$.  Similarly the number of three-element compositions is the coefficient of $x^3$ which is $3$.    If it helps, $1+x+\cdots+x^n = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ so you could have expanded $\left(\frac{1-x^{2+1}}{1-x}\right)^1\left(\frac{1-x^{1+1}}{1-x}\right)^2$ with the same result

Comment: Ooh thank you, that's a really cool idea, I can see how it works in relation to binominal stuff I've learned before

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have to chose $m$ elements and there are $n$ subsets of equal elements. If every subset of equal elements has more or equal elements than $m$ then the formula is simply $(\binom{n}{m})=\binom{n+m-1}{m}$ and the cost of computing it is $O(n+m)$ since you have to compute the factorial of $n+m-1$ and other smaller factorials. This formula doesn't work for the general case, in fact if some sets have less elements than $m$ you can't do it that way, but there's an algorithm that works in $O(nm)$ that solves the general case, and it is based on dynamic programming. The main idea is that if you have let's say a set which is in the form $[a_1,a_1,...,a_1,a_2,a_2,...,a_2,......,a_k,a_k,...,a_k,a_{k+1},a_{k+1},...,a_{k+1}]$ and you have to chose $m$ elements and there are $n$ $a_{k+1}$, let's say you have all the combinations of $0,1,2,3,..,m$ elements for the set $[a_1,a_1,...,a_1,a_2,a_2,...,a_2,......,a_k,a_k,...,a_k]$. Since we can add $0,1,2,...,n$ $a_{k+1}$ to a old combination the resulting combinations with $m$ elements will be the old combinations with $m$ elements plus $0$ $a_{k+1}$, the old combinations with $m-1$ elements plus $1$ $a_{k+1}$, the old combinations with $m-2$ elements plus $2$ $a_{k+1}$ and so on. Since the formal algorithm would be very long to write I'll give an example.

The set is $[1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5]$ and we have to get the number of combinations with $m=5$ elements. We will manage an array of 6 elements representing the number of combinations with 0,1,2,3,4,5 elements at a certain time.

$arr_0=[1,0,0,0,0,0]$ since there is one empty set. Now we have to add the first subset which is made of 2 elements (1,1) so we put $span=2$, that means that the new array will have in each position the current value plus the sum of the 2 previous positions of the current array(the positions behind element 0 are considered 0).

$[1,0,0,0,0,0]-->[(1),0,0,0,0,0]$

$[(1),0,0,0,0,0]-->[1,(1),0,0,0,0]$

$[(1),(0),0,0,0,0]-->[(1,1,(1),0,0,0]$

$[1,(0),(0),0,0,0]-->[(1,1,1,(0),0,0]$

$[1,0,(0),(0),0,0]-->[(1,1,1,0,(0),0]$

$[1,0,0,(0),(0),0]-->[(1,1,1,0,0,(0)]$

$arr_1=[1,1,1,0,0,0]$. Now we add the second subset which is made of 3 elements (2,2,2) so we put $span=3$.

$[1,1,1,0,0,0]-->[(1),1,1,0,0,0]$

$[(1),1,1,0,0,0]-->[1,(2),1,0,0,0]$

$[(1),(1),1,0,0,0]-->[1,2,(3),0,0,0]$

$[(1),(1),(1),0,0,0]-->[1,2,3,(3),0,0]$

$[1,(1),(1),(0),0,0]-->[1,2,3,3,(2),0]$

$[1,1,(1),(0),(0),0]-->[1,2,3,3,2,(1)]$

$arr_2=[1,2,3,3,2,1]$. We add (3), $span=1$.

$arr_3=[1,3,5,6,5,3]$. We add (4,4), $span=2$.

$arr_4=[1,4,9,14,16,14]$. We add (5,5,5), $span=3$.

$arr_5=[1,5,14,28,43,53]$

So 53 is our answer, in order to do less operations instead of sum up the last $span$ elements of the old array we can just sum the previous element of the new array and subtract the element $span +1$ positions behind so that the cost of the algorithm is $O(nm)$ as mentioned before.